# MySQL Insert and Update trigger issue

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to achieve row level auditing by capturing user id and timestamp for inserts and updates separately. But for some reason, the insert trigger is firing even for updates and the two insert_* columns get updated every time (For updates as well).
Please help.

Table

```
create table test
(id varchar(30) primary key,
insert_id varchar(30),
insert_timestamp timestamp, 
update_id varchar(30), 
update_timestamp timestamp);
```

BEFORE INSERT trigger

```
 DELIMITER //
    create trigger ins_test 
    before insert on test 
    for each row 
    Begin
    set new.insert_id = session_user();
    set new.insert_timestamp = now();
    End;
    //
```

BEFORE UPDATE trigger

```
  DELIMITER //
    create trigger upd_test 
    before update on test 
    for each row 
    Begin
    set new.update_id = session_user();
    set new.update_timestamp = now();
    End;
    //
```

-Ganesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in MySQL 5.5.30 in SQL Fiddle and the triggers work properly.

You should explicitly define the timestamp columns as NULL if you don't want them to default to current_timestamp on insert:

```
create table test
(
  id varchar(30) primary key,
  insert_id varchar(30) null,
  insert_timestamp timestamp null, 
  update_id varchar(30) null, 
  update_timestamp timestamp null
);
```

Try this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0eda/1) to see your triggers working properly. I added a 1 second sleep between each statement so you can tell that the insert_timestamp does not change on update.

Comment: Thanks for this! Defining the timestamp columns as NULL worked.